# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

In attempting to run the following in PyCharm 2017.3.1:

```
with open('../data/UrbanSound8K/retrained_graph.pb', 'rb') as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```

I receive the following:

```
/anaconda/bin/python3 /Users/PycharmProjects/UrbanSound/src/recognize_sound.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PycharmProjects/UrbanSound/src/recognize_sound.py", line 12, in <module>
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'
```

Here is some environment information:

```
(tensorflow) $ python3 -c 'import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)'
1.4.0
(tensorflow) $ python -V
Python 3.6.2
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Resolved: I corrected my virtualenv to point to tensorflow.

Comment: Which version of TF is supposed to support a public interface for `GraphDef`?

Comment: @B33l238u8 could you please explain how you corrected your virtualenv to point to tensorflow? I'm having the same problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You ran `python3 -c ...` for tf version, but you ran `python -V` for your python version, is python3 set as 3.6.2 (same as python) ?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it using

> python36 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.14

Comment: `Collecting tensorflow-gpu==1.14
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu==1.14 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu==1.14`

I got this error.

Comment: I resolved it using `python3 -m pip install tensorflow==1.14`

Answer (score 1):

use "tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()" instead if you are using tensorflow 2.0

Answer (score 1):

disable V2 behavior

```
import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf 
tf.disable_v2_behavior()
```

or use this `tf.compat.v1.GraphDef()`